# Laravel 4 - Call Controller from Routes closures

Tags: php, laravel

I'm newbie in Laravel 4, I just want to set config when runtime in Routes (closures) before calling a controller. But it not work.
Here is my routes :

```
Route::get('/test', array(function(){
    $config = [
        'config_url' => 'https://demo.com/'
    ];

    \Config::set('app.test', 'test');
    \Config::set('config',$config);
    echo "123";die();
}, 'uses' => 'UserController@estimate_time'));
```

It go to the Action `estimate_time` of `UserController` and not run the function.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you cannot use the route like this, because `function(){}` is equal to `'use'`. I suppose that is a either-or relationship between `function(){}` and `['use'=>'XXX']`.

Maybe you can set all those config to be a middleware and then use:

```
Route::get('/test', ['uses' => 'UserController@estimate_time']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think route file is not the best place to set config. You either do it in your middleware or in your controller.